# Taking APP offline before deploy using CICD Azure Dev ops

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

The Azure App Service Deployment Task has a checkbox for taking app offline under Additional Deployment Options: Take App Offline. if I check that is it sufficient to take APP offline ? How do I automate the process of adding app_offline.htm ?

Take Application Offline: Select the option to take the AzureRM Web App offline by placing an app_offline.htm file in the root directory of the Web App before the sync operation begins. The file will be removed after the sync operation completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `Take App Offline` option in `IIS Web Deploy`, should be useful to you.

[image]

**Offical Doc:**

[Azure Pipelines : Use this task to deploy a website or web app using WebDeploy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 1):

The option takes offline is good when it's an app that users do not use often. But the better approach would be the second one you mentioned of displaying an app_offline.htm. This can be done by creating a slot called maintenance and then adding a step in your pipeline with the [Azure App Service Manage task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops) to swap the slots, then deploy your code and then again swap the slots with the same task

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure App service with CICD in Azure DevOps, a more elegant solution would be to use deployment slots instead. This way you can deploy your app to the staging environment first, then swap staging with your production with zero downtime and lag. Since both your production and staging apps use the same app service, you will have no additional cost. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/stage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots/